# javascript - find the length of a label and if it is empty?

Tags: javascript

I have a label that is sometimes empty.  How do I set up a conditional statement on the client side to test this?

i have

```
var label = document.getElementByID("<%=label1.ClientID %>").innerHTMl;
```

to get the text, but i can't seem to figure out an if..else statment if it is empty or not.  label.length == 0; label == null, etc don't seem to work.  any help?

Comment: @halp - corrected typo on the title of question.

Comment: What is the value of the label when it is empty(if it is '' then label.length should work)?

Comment: @BYK The value is uninitialized - it is set onpageload if somethign else occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if(label){
  // The label is defined
}
```

Neither the if nor an else on it may execute if its undefined, so best not to use an else on this (seems weird, but I just did a check with Firefox).

Comment: This is rather elegant. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something better:

```
var id = "<%= label1.ClientID %>";
var label = id.length > 0 ? document.getElementById(id).innerHTML : "";
```

(Assuming this is Ruby here...)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 var labelID = '<%=label1.ClientID %>';
 if (labelID.length!=0)
     var label = document.getElementByID(labelID).innerHTMl;
 else...
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty string is falsy, as is something that's null.

If the label always exists (document.getElementByID("<%=label1.ClientID %>") always returns an html element) then the above should work.

However, the label may only appear to be empty. It could have a blank string inside it. So try this:

```
var label = document.getElementByID("<%=label1.ClientID %>").innerHTMl;
if (label.replace(/\s/g, '')) {
    // handle it
}
```